# Why does CSS selector only style first matching svg path

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm working with an inline SVG element that's made of two paths.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt63c1h0/20/)

HTML:

```
<svg class="flag" width="22px" height="22px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
       <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
           <g>
              <path class="flag-path" d="M7.46666667,6.6875 L7.46666667,17 L6,17 L6,6.6875 C6,6.30780664 6.32832708,6 6.73333333,6 C7.13833958,6 7.46666667,6.30780664 7.46666667,6.6875 Z" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"></path>
              <path class="flag-path" d="M14.8,7.85094336 C15.6761729,7.85094336 16.4625125,7.40383203 17,7.065625 L17,13.4646387 C16.4625125,13.8028672 15.6761729,14.25 14.8,14.25 C13.9238271,14.25 13.1374875,14.0064746 12.6,13.6682461 C12.0625125,13.330082 11.2761729,13.0865566 10.4,13.0865566 C9.52382708,13.0865566 8.73751042,13.5045996 8.2,13.8427637 L8.2,7.44375 C8.73751042,7.10554297 9.52382708,6.6875 10.4,6.6875 C11.2761729,6.6875 12.0625125,6.93100391 12.6,7.26921094 C13.1374875,7.60741797 13.9238271,7.85094336 14.8,7.85094336 L14.8,7.85094336 L14.8,7.85094336 Z" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)"></path>
           </g>
       </g>
</svg>
```

I've got some CSS and JS that's supposed to animate the color of the paths from white to green on click.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt63c1h0/20/)

```
.change-flag {
    animation: change-flag 750ms;
    fill: rgba(58,255,118,1);
}

@keyframes change-flag {
    from { fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) }
    to { fill: rgba(58,255,118,1); }
}
```

js [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt63c1h0/20/)

```
var flagCircle = document.querySelector('.el');
var flag = document.querySelector('.flag-path');
var anywhere = document.querySelector('html');

var highlightFlag = function () {
    flagCircle.classList.toggle('change-circle');
    flag.classList.toggle('change-flag');
};

anywhere.addEventListener('click', highlightFlag, false);
```

When the event is triggered and the animation executed, only one of the paths turns green. What's going on here?

Comment: Is flag returning an array of your paths?

Comment: @LiamSchauerman err, I don't think so. Should it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) only returns one (the first) element matched by the given selector. Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) instead

```
var flagCircle = document.querySelector('.el');
var paths = document.querySelectorAll('.flag-path');
//...

var highlightFlag = function () {
    //...
    for (var i = 0, l = paths.length; i < l; i++) {
        paths[i].classList.toggle("change-flag");
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdpqg74t/

Comment: I take it that `.querySelectorAll` creates an array, then the other bit of code you changed is iterating through that array, toggling `change-flag` on each. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, but its not exactly an array but a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). It acts like an array but has some differences (see the link).